# How to type @ in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, helpfile

I'm from Bosnia and I don't know how to type @ in Ubuntu. I'm a newbie in Ubuntu. I'm using Bosnian keyboard layout and my shortcut for typing @ is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: You mean using it in a terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can:

1. Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> and press <kbd>u</kbd> to enter into Unicode Composition mode.
2. Release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>.
3. Then type `0040`.
4. Finally press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

I tried now with this keyboard layout.

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> +  <kbd>V</kbd>  worked for me. <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is the "alt" one on the right.

[image]